# SQL Server Agent randomly stops working however says its running in Services though the agent is dead (Forced restart fixes it)

Tags: sql-server, server, restart, agent

I've not seen this scenario in all my web searches.
We have several SQL Server Agent jobs that get kicked off by users through various applications.
Quite randomly, these executions will fail. When log in and manually kick the jobs off i'm immediately presented with 'SQL Agent not started' errors.
When I check the agent it says it's running. If I force a restart the problem is fixed.

The random nature of the issue causes testing issues.
The agent is already set up to 'restart if stopped unexpectedly' and 'restart with delay'.

A recent disaster recovery was performed and SQL Server Agent started successfully and declared itself 'running'. However once again it required a manual restart to actually work.

Is this a known issue or bug?

How can I mitigate against this when the agent says its running and all parameters are set correctly and meet the 'internet's' suggestions?

Comment: What does the agent job do?

Comment: It kicks off a myriad of agent jobs. Jobs that kick off backups, run stored procedures, perform maintenance.

Comment: Can you try running the job(s) from another instance

Comment: From your explanation, you are likely encounter locking and blocking issues

Comment: What is your process for starting the instance? Do you start the DB engine service, and also start the agent service (either via auto service startup, or via script, etc)? If so, I suggest that you instead set the database engine service to manual, and set only agent to automatic. Starting agent will cause the engine to start because of service dependencies. I have seen situations where the engine seems unable to tell that agent has started, but I have never seen that happen when using the agent service as the trigger for the engine service.

Comment: Thanks for replies.
This problem isn't limited to the start up. In fact it rarely happens at start up. It will randomly become 'frozen' during the day. Sometimes weeks/months apart. 
Most jobs are scheduled and don't clash with each other.
The jobs that are initiated via users perform checks and will hold in a time loop until the last job is complete. We've also stress tested those jobs with 15 users spamming at the same time to ensure no issues.
Whatever this is, it seems to just 'freeze'. The only errors are those of the failed agent job executions following the agent 'freeze'.

Comment: @ChanGuanYu This literally has nothing to do with locking / blocking. OP is talking about the SQL Server Agent service itself, not a specific job. KBL1974, when you say "*However once again it required a manual restart to actually work*" how are you restarting it?...through the UI in SSMS (by right clicking on the Agent node and clicking Restart) or are you restarting the Windows service running on your server? Have you checked the Windows Event Log for any errors around when the issue arises?...I would bet the service is stopped on the Windows server, when you run into this issue.